# Mysql to Json encoded array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am creating a json array with data from mysql:

```
$array = $db->query("SELECT .............")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print json_encode($array);
```

This returns:

```
[{"animal":"alpaca"},{"animal":"buffalo"},{"animal":"cat"},{"animal":"tiger"}]
```

But I need it to return data with the following syntax:

```
 ["alpaca","buffalo","cat","tiger"]
```

Any hints on how to achieve this?

Comment: Need to change FETCH_ASSOC because it returns associative array

Comment: or `print json_encode(array_values($array));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can simply use `array_values` over here but for an alteration you can also use `array_column` like as

```
$array = $db->query("SELECT .............")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print json_encode(array_column($array,'animal'));
```

> Note: `array_column()` requires **PHP > 5.5.0**

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_values()` for your issue:

```
$array = json_encode(array_values($array));
```

Comment: This returns    [{"animal":"alpaca"},{"animal":"tiger"}]